# Standard messages for reporting system metrics

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any standard message types or nodes for monitoring and reporting system metrics like memory, cpu and disk usage?

I'm trying to create a simple dashboard, and I'd like to capture and display these, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. However, I don't see anything relevant in [std_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs) or [common_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/common_msgs).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232697/standard-messages-for-reporting-system-metrics/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I typically monitor this type of information through the ROS diagnostics system.

[diagnostics_common_diagnostics](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_common_diagnostics?distro=jade) contains nodes for monitoring disk space, clock sync and a few others.

[libsensors_monitor](http://wiki.ros.org/libsensors_monitor) also contains a ROS node for monitoring the sensors available through the kernel sensors API and making that information available through the ROS diagnostics API.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0